# Does stopping IIS7 application pool kill any currently executing requests?

Tags: iis-7

Does stopping an IIS7 application pool kill any currently executing requests? Or does it wait for all requests to complete?

Please notice, I am asking about **stopping the pool, not recycling it**.

Comment: It kills all simply.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a documentation which supports your statement?

Comment: There is no documentation for everything.